# Traveling salesman with a twist: must visit each node twice and must "wait" between returning to each node?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming, approximation

Please be kind if this question violates the rules as I am still working on my Stack Exchange question-asking intuition.

The motivation for this problem is the optimal deployment of automated lawnmowers.

**The problem** Let there be $n$ nodes (lawns) in a fully-connected, undirected graph with defined edge lengths $\textbf{E}_{ij}$ (basic TSP).

The graph exhibits triangle equality, $\textbf{E}_{ij} + \textbf{E}_{jk} \geq \textbf{E}_{ik} \forall \space i, j, k$ in the graph. Ie A->B->C must not be faster than A->C. I have a feeling this property has a name but I don't know it.

**First twist** You must visit each node at least twice.

**Second twist** After the first visit to each node $\textbf{V}_i$, you must travel (wait) $\textbf{W}_i$ units of distance (time) before returning to node $\textbf{V}_i$ for the second visit. For additional visits, this constraint does not apply: no further waiting necessary.

If a node has been visited once it is considered "open." When an open node is visited (so that node is visited twice so far in total) it is considered "closed".

**Third twist** You may only have $m$ "open" nodes at a time. If you traverse the graph, hitting each node only once, you must turn back and visit one of those once-visited nodes before moving on to your first touch of the $m^{th}$ node.

You can also wait at a node if you want.

**The goal is to hit all nodes at least twice with the least distance/time traveled**

**My thoughts so far** I know the TSP is not perfectly solved. I usually use the [Elastic Net](https://www.nature.com/articles/326689a0) for the original TSP. So I'm guessing these twists have not been solved. I think the solution to the first twist would just be to repeat the one-pass TSP twice—but haven't proven it.

My answerable question is: Has this problem been formalized? Has anyone approximated it in a computationally feasible way? It seems to me that with the fame of the TSP, someone has at least thought of this before. But I am having a hard time using the right verbiage to find that work on Google scholar, arXiv, etc.

Comment: The name for your distance condition with the $\ge$ is "triangle equality".

Comment: @MishaLavrov An "open" node has been visited once. Just edited to clarify.